# Angular. How to use observable?

Tags: angular, typescript

This question seems to widely discussed, though I not find how to implement properly.

I have two methods in Component, that could run in parallel, so I have a timing issue now. How to use observable (or promise) to ensure ngAfterViewChecked() runs after onCollapse()?

**Component**

```
@Component
export class MyClass implements AfterViewChecked{
    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        ...
    }

    onCollapse(index: number) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="collapse_section" *ngFor="let event of event_role; let i = index" #jobBody>
    <header accordion-heading (click)="onCollapse(i)" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed">
        ...
    </header>
</div>
```

**Update 1** To make it clear what I am doing here:

The idea is when user clicks, onCollapse called and some div becomes visible, but it could be out of screen. Then to make it appear on screen, I want to scroll within ngAfterViewChecked call. I cannot scroll within onCollapse() because view is not updated within this handler scope.

**Update 2**

Probably I not need ngAfterViewChecked at all, and it could be other method. I just want to scroll window to bottom, once all DOM manipulations caused by click done. Is it possible with Observable and (click) event handler?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why do you want it to run after `ngAfterViewChecked`? Do you know that angular runs that method many many times? And looking at the html it looks that you want to run `onCollapse` on user click. So I am afraid, there has little to do with Observables

Comment: I make update to make clear what I am doing here. Please check.

Comment: Probably you right about exactly these two methods cannot be linked with observable, but could it be that observable will be used to call some method with page scrolling exactly after click event done?

Answer (score 0):

What work does ngAfterViewChecked() do? If it does some asynchronous call that returns a promise, you could do this:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
this.someAsynchronousCall()
.then(() => this.onCollapse(index));
}
```

if your async calls returns an observable, then you could do,

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
this.someAsynchronousCallThatReturnsObservable()
.toPromise()
.then(() => this.onCollapse(index));
}
```

Comment: ngAfterViewChecked manipulates with DOM objects. The idea is when user clicks onCollapse called and some div becomes visible, but it could be out of screen. Then to make it appear on screen, I want to scroll within ngAfterViewChecked call. I cannot scroll within onCollapse() because view is not updated within this handler scope.

Comment: so basically, you want to scroll to the bottom when a user clicks on an element that triggers onCollapse()?

Comment: I need: user click -> then show div on page -> then scroll to bottom